# Flutter, couldn't convert string to Date time format

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, flutter-intl, flutter-datetime-picker

I got data input in `TextField` using `showDatePicker`. I converted the selected data to String and parsed it to the format `dd-mm-yy` using intl format. According to docs `DateFormat('ymd')` is the way to do that. But I get the error `FormatException: Trying to read m from 2022-06-04 00:00:00.000 at position 4`. What is right way to convert to that format and why am I getting that error.
docs that I referred - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

code

```
TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                  controller: paidDateController,
                  onTap: () async {
                    DateTime? PickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                        firstDate: DateTime(2010),
                        lastDate: DateTime(2026));

                    if (PickedDate != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        formatDate = PickedDate.toString();
                        paidDate = DateFormat('ymd').parse(formatDate);
                        print(paidDate);
                      });
                    } else {
                      Get.snackbar('Error', 'Pick paid date',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red);
                    }
                  },
                  decoration:
                      kTextFieldDecocation.copyWith(hintText: 'Paid Date'),
                ),
```

`formatDate` is string data type and `paidDate` is date time data type.

Comment: DateFormat you should put is either DateFormat('yMd') or DateFormat.yMd() and it's start a pattern date like this "05/06/2022" if you wanted to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm ithink the formating you giving to this part

```
paidDate = DateFormat('ymd').parse(formatDate);
```

show always error since if you tried to parse the date was format given by showDateTimePicker would be like `2022-06-05 15:00:12` which also if you try to pass this. This would like likely not to parse since `DateFormat('yMd')` or `DateFormat.yMd()` which the reading pattern date of this is like this `"05/06/2022"`
so you try to is like this

```
final formatDate1 = "2022-05-06";
   final formForMatted = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(formatDate1));
   final  paidDate1 = DateFormat.yMd().parse(formForMatted);
   print(paidDate1); // as result 2022-06-05 00:00:00.000
```

but if you wanted a result like 5/6/2022
try this

```
final formatDate1 = "2022-05-06";
   final paidDate1 = DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.parse(formatDate1));
   print(paidDate1); // as result 5/6/2022
```

Comment: Understood the error, I tried ``` formatDate = PickedDate.toString().replaceAll("00:00:00.000", "");``` and then parsing it but I got ```FormatException: Trying to read m from 2022-06-04  at position 4``` error

Comment: And ```DateFormat.().format()``` is used to convert DateTime data type to string and ```.parse()``` is vice-versa.